# Can't find Cisco CSR1000v image for deploying in GCP

Tags: virtualization, cisco, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I would like to deploy Cisco CSR1000v on VM instance but I cannot find it among the OS images in GCP, neither custom images and marketplace.
I'm following the tutorial below: 
https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/gcp/b_csrgcp/b_csrgcp_chapter_01.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be new, but there is a csr 1000v image in GCP you can launch. Tip: search for "1000v" not "CSR".

On the licensing, the base image in GCP I believe can be run indefinitely at 1Mbps limit. You can also get a trial license from http://www.cisco.com/go/license. Cisco.com account and possibly licensing setup required.

Otherwise the link you used is good reference.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you misunderstood, The Cisco CSR1000v image is not provided by GCP. The Cisco CSR 1000v on GCP supports the following license model:
Bring Your Own License Model. The cost of licensing using BYOL in GCP includes the cost of a GCP instance and the cost of a Cisco CSR 1000v license.

First, you need to purchase Licensing for a Cisco CSR 1000v from Cisco to be used on Google Cloud Platform. See the attached link[1][2] for details. Also, see this link[3] on how to activate Cisco CSR 1000v Licenses.

Once you have your image ready to use in Google Cloud Platform, you can use the following links [4] and [5] on how to export and deploy your image in GCP.

There are a couple of things you need to take into consideration while launching CSR1000v in GCP:

1. Create an instance with one vCPU and 4 GB memory. At boot disk option, click 'change,' go to ‘custom image’ e.g.click ‘cisco csr-image-eft,’ as a project and then use this image ‘csr1000veft0529 from this project, keep the disk size to 8 GB
2. Make sure you enable IP forwarding on the CSR interface.
3. And make sure you block project wide SSH keys, and we only support the custom keys, so  you need to copy paste the custom keys to login 
   4.Launch CSR on GCP

i)Generate your own key

> ssh-keygen-trsa-fgcp/csr-Ccsr
>   ii)Create a VPC or use default VPC
>   iii)Launch CSR VM
>   select custom image for a boot disk
>   enable IP forwarding
>   copy your created *public*key
>   Disable project level key

5. Login CSR

Also, note that it's not guaranteed the image will work on GCP, any issues running it might need you to reach out to Cisco Support.

[1]https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/gcp/b_csrgcp/b_csrgcp_chapter_00.html 
[2]https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/gcp/b_csrgcp/b_csrgcp_chapter_00.html#id_73838
[3]https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/csr1000/software/configuration/b_CSR1000v_Configuration_Guide/b_CSR1000v_Configuration_Guide_chapter_01000.html#d23248e174a1635 [4] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/import-existing-image
[5] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/importing-virtual-disks